# Iframe is invoked for the second time page refresh

Tags: php, iframe

I have included an iframe in a page. But that is invoked for the second time I refeesh the page.

Please help me in solving this.

Comment: <?php html_header_show();
echo '<iframe src="http://www........></iframe>'; 
?>

Comment: It is unreadable, please edit your question instead of adding code as comment.

Comment: Your question is hard to understand, and does not include enough information... however, if I understand your problem: The `IFrame` *should* be 'invoked' a second time when you refresh the page. Why would you expect it not to be?

Comment: no.. i meant as, i have an iframe in the login page.. but that iframe for getting the credentials and do auto login. so when logged in the site2, and in site1 if i refresh the page it does not get the credentials,but that is done if i refresh the page again(second) time.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:

The Problem is because the Page is loaded from the cache not loaded as fresh page. So when I refresh the page the second time.. the page gets refreshed and the Iframe is invoked.
So I tried to refresh the page manually when invoked for the first time alone.
So the Page won't be refreshed every time when you leave the page ideal.
The solution is:

```
if (!isset($_GET['reload']))
{
  echo '<meta http-equiv=Refresh content="0;url=yourpage.php?reload=1">';
}
```

So this would refresh the page only once when invoked for the first time.
Hope this helps someone with the same issue.

Comment: A more common solution to this problem is to add junk querystring data to the page's URL for each call, for example a numeric value representing the system ticks. It has no effect on the loading of the page at all, but because it makes the URL different every time, it is never pulled from a cached version. This could still experience cached loads sometimes.